# Find all paths in a tree type of structure

Tags: algorithms

The language I am using is C#, but I am looking more for help with the algorithm more than I am concerned with which language.  I have been trying to develop this algorithm for a while now and I can't seem to get it down.

I have a tree like structure which has many parent/child relationships.  So leaf #1 can have children, and the children can have children, and so on and so on. This forms a tree.  My problem is that I want to be able to list out every possible path down the tree to the bottom.

My data is in a C# list of objects and each object has 2 fields, parent and child.

So my data could look something like this:

```
Parent       Child

1              2

1              3

2              4

2              5

3              6

3              7

3              8

4              9

4              10
```

My real data is more complex than this as I have thousands of rows.  In the sample above here is the results I want to achieve:

```
1  2  4  9

1  2  4  10

1  2  4

1  2  5

1  3  6

1  3  7
```

I did see some other similar solutions on this website, but they were a little different than what I need.  A leaf in my tree can have more than 2 children as shown above.

Comment: It sounds like you could do this alongside an ordinary depth-first tree traversal by having a stack that you push onto every time you go "down" a node and pop from every time you go "up" a node, then print every time you find yourself at a leaf node. Is there some other wrinkle complication we're missing? Is your data structure actually not a tree? (you called it "tree-like" but everything else you say about it implies it is a real tree so I'm not sure)

Comment: Is the data stored in a database, something you can run queries against?

Comment: When you say leaf node, I assume you mean a node with no children, correct?  I guess you could call it a tree.

Comment: The data starts out in a database and then winds up in C# lists.

Comment: This is related to the topic of "Tree Traversal" - Many well written examples are all over the net. See for example:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal